# How to Reuse Textx Model

Tags: python, parsing, dsl, textx

I'm using textx ([documentation](http://www.igordejanovic.net/textX/)) as DSL parser and my application would greatly benefit from re-use of both textx metamodels and models.

I tried with pickle, but I realized I can't pickle textx objects.

Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: I stumbled upon this old post and realized that I might misinterpreted your question. By "reuse" you mean reuse of already constructed Python objects? Can you please clarify your use case?

Answer (score 0):

There is a support for grammar reuse [using `import` keyword](http://www.igordejanovic.net/textX/grammar/#grammar-modularization). Be aware that your grammar files must reside under the same tree as you can't import arbitrary path.

For splitting model and referencing elements across files there is a recent contribution which is not released at the time of this post but is merged into the `master` branch.

You can read about the contribution [here](https://github.com/igordejanovic/textX/pull/55) and see final cleaned up version [here](https://github.com/igordejanovic/textX/pull/57).